# Separating Background and Foreground

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am new to Matlab and to Image Processing as well. I am working on separating background and foreground in images like this

[image: passport image blue background]

I have hundreds of images like this, found [here](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/facesketch.html). By trial and error I found out a threshold (in RGB space): the red layer is always less than 150 and the green and blue layers are greater than 150 where the background is.

so if my RGB image is `I` and my `r`,`g` and `b` layers are

```
redMatrix = I(:,:,1);
greenMatrix = I(:,:,2);
blueMatrix = I(:,:,3);
```

by finding coordinates where in red, green and blue the values are greater or less than 150 I can get the coordinates of the background like

```
[r1 c1] = find(redMatrix < 150);
[r2 c2] = find(greenMatrix > 150);
[r3 c3] = find(blueMatrix > 150);
```

now I get coordinates of thousands of pixels in `r1,c1,r2,c2,r3 and c3`.

**My questions:**

1. How to find common values, like the coordinates of the pixels where red is less than 150 and green and blue are greater than 150? 
   I have to iterate every coordinate of `r1` and `c1` and check if they occur in `r2 c2` and `r3 c3` to check it is a common point. but that would be very expensive.
   **Can this be achieved without a loop** ?
2. If somehow I came up with common points like `[commonR commonC]` and `commonR` and `commonC` are both of order `5000 X 1`, so to access this background pixel of Image `I`, I have to access first `commonR` then `commonC` and then access image `I` like

   `I(commonR(i,1),commonC(i,1))`

that is expensive too. So again my question is can this be done without loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

**I got solution with @Science_Fiction answer's**

Just elaborating his/her answer

I used

```
mask = I(:,:,1) < 150 & I(:,:,2) > 150 & I(:,:,3) > 150;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach seems basic but decent. Since for this particular image the background is composed of mainly blue so you be crude and do:

```
mask = img(:,:,3) > 150;
```

This will set those pixels which evaluate to true for > 150 to 0 and false to 1. You will have a black and white image though.

```
imshow(mask);
```

To add colour back

```
mask3d(:,:,1) = mask; 
mask3d(:,:,2) = mask; 
mask3d(:,:,3) = mask;

img(mask3d) = 255;
imshow(img);
```

Should give you the colour image of face hopefully, with a pure white background. All this requires some trial and error.

Comment: this approach is helpful, but still when I am adding color back, it still replace some part of face as well.

Comment: Yes, since this is a crude method. Some parts of the face will have a high level of blue so will be set to 0. You could play around with the numbers more and include checks on the R and G as well. Will require lots of trial and error as said.

Comment: A more general approach to find the threshold (150 in this case) is by using the Otsu's algorithm. This function is built in matlab.

Answer (score 4):

No loop is needed. You could do it like this:

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
redMatrix = I(:,:,1);
greenMatrix = I(:,:,2);
blueMatrix = I(:,:,3);
J(:,:,1) = redMatrix < 150;
J(:,:,2) = greenMatrix > 150;
J(:,:,3) = blueMatrix > 150;
J = 255 * uint8(J);
imshow(J);
```

[image]

A greyscale image would also suffice to separate the background.

```
K = ((redMatrix < 150) + (greenMatrix > 150) + (blueMatrix > 150))/3;
imshow(K);
```

[image]

### EDIT

I had another look, also using the other images you linked to.
Given the variance in background colors, I thought you would get better results deriving a threshold value from the image histogram instead of hardcoding it.

Occasionally, this algorithm is a little to rigorous, e.g. erasing part of the clothes together with the background. But I think over 90% of the images are separated pretty well, which is more robust than what you could hope to achieve with a fixed threshold.

```
close all;

path = 'C:\path\to\CUHK_training_cropped_photos\photos';
files = dir(path);
bins = 16;

for f = 3:numel(files)
    fprintf('%i/%i\n', f, numel(files));
    file = files(f);
    if isempty(strfind(file.name, 'jpg'))
        continue
    end

    I = imread([path filesep file.name]);

    % Take the histogram of the blue channel
    B = I(:,:,3);
    h = imhist(B, bins);
    h2 = h(bins/2:end);

    % Find the most common bin in the *upper half*
    % of the histogram 
    m = bins/2 + find(h2 == max(h2));

    % Set the threshold value somewhat below  
    % the value corresponding to that bin
    thr = m/bins - .25;
    BW = im2bw(B, thr);
    % Pad with ones to ensure background connectivity
    BW = padarray(BW, [1 1], 1);
    % Find connected regions in BW image
    CC = bwconncomp(BW);    
    L = labelmatrix(CC);
    % Crop back again
    L = L(2:end-1,2:end-1);

    % Set the largest region in the orignal image to white
    for c = 1:3
        channel = I(:,:,c);
        channel(L==1) = 255;
        I(:,:,c) = channel;
    end 

    % Show the results with a pause every 16 images    
    subplot(4,4,mod(f-3,16)+1);
    imshow(I);
    title(sprintf('Img %i, thr %.3f', f, thr));

    if mod(f-3,16)+1 == 16
        pause
        clf
    end    

end

pause
close all;
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: brother thank you for your answer, but this approach is changing person's coordinate value, cant I do it without changing them ?